# Use CSS Child and Last Selector on same element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I have different links using glyphicons in a bootstrap `panel-footer` like shown below:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <a href class="pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    </a>
    <a href class="pull-right margin-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see, I need to apply an additional margin to the last `a`-child element by using my own `margin-right` class:

```css
.margin-right {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The above code can be found in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mr7YLHGEH0sL2AlQRcoF).

---

Since this seems to be kind of an ugly workaround I thought about using the CSS child selector in combination with the `:last-element` selector to select the desired element and apply the needed `margin-right`. What I came up with is like this:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <a href="#" class="pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I replaced the `margin-right` style in my CSS-file with the following:

```css
.panel-footer > a:last-child {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

However, this does not result in the wanted result. There is no `margin-right` applied to the desired child element as you can see in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/b1J2GAXKvgwm6Ltkj7Ua).

How can I select the last child element in the way I want to and apply the desired `margin-right`?

Comment: That seems correct to me because the `a` is your last child. Can you create a demo?

Comment: Did you applied display:block or inline-block to a element? or can you try something like .panel-footer > .pull-right:last-child { display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; }

Comment: I suspect this is a specificity issue. The class would have a higher specificty that the pseudo-class.

Comment: The code you supplied works correctly.

Comment: @Harry: I provided the two snippets at plunkr and added the links to my question.

Comment: @j08691: Please see my two plunks I added to my question. Does not seem to work as desired.

Comment: @albert: That makes the problem amply clear. You missed out one part of the `panel-footer` when posting the code initially. The last `div` present within it means that the `a` **is not the last-child** and so you'd have to use `a:last-of-type`. I am feeling a little uneasy at adding this an answer because worldojr had provided this as a solution (I know his reasoning was wrong but still). I have retracted my close vote because the problem is now reproducible.

Comment: Yes, .panel-footer a:last-of-type { margin-right: 5px; } should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:last-of-type` pseudo-class instead of `:last-child`:

```
.panel-footer a:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: My apologies, @Harry - I see you got there 3mins before me while I was over at the plunk, investigating the CSS.

Comment: No worries @Rounin. I wasn't planning on posting it anyway and there is no way that you'd have known about the other user who posted that initially. He had removed his answer because his reasoning was off the mark.